# ListControl.DataBind() doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

i've stuck with problem. I have an ASP.NET project with dynamically creating controls. Even more many controls depend on another controls (on postback), so they could change their appearance.

I have ListControl and binds it with data in one method:

```
public static class ListControlExtensions
{
    public static void BindList(this ListControl list, IEnumerable dataSource, string valueKey, string textKey)
    {
        list.Items.Clear();
        list.Items.Add(new ListItem("(Empty)", "-1"));

        list.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        list.DataSource = dataSource;
        list.DataValueField = valueKey;
        list.DataTextField = textKey;
        list.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The incoming dataSource is good (as expected due to business logic), but rendered list control haven't changed since last BindList. So problem - list control after fist databind (with default dataSource) doesn't change after later databind.

The **BindList** invokes at the OnInit:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    if (CompaniesList != null)
    {
        BindCompaniesList(CompaniesList, valueToFilter);
    }
}

protected void BindCompaniesList(ListControl listToBind, String valueToFilter)
{
    if (listToBind != null)
    {
        var list = Helper.GetCompanies();
        foreach (var item in list.Where(item => item.Value == valueToFilter))
        {
            item.Value = "-1";
        }
        listToBind.BindList(list, "Value", "Text");        
     }
}
```

**FIXED:** The solution: I think problem is that LoadViewState happens after OnInit and it overwrites the ListControl with the previous data, stored at ViewState. So I've moved DataBind to OnLoad from OnInit, and cached the selected value, because binding resets it.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (CompaniesList != null)
    {
        var selected = CompaniesList.SelectedIndex;
        BindCompaniesList(CompaniesList, valueToFilter);
        CompaniesList.SelectedIndex = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean only first time your list is binded but not on postback?

Comment: i bind every time, when control is loaded - but I think problem was that LoadViewState happened after OnInit and it overwrites the ListControl with the previous data, stored at ViewState. So I've moved the binding to the OnLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the binding code to OnLoad and depending on how your code works it should look something like this

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack())
{
      if (CompaniesList != null)      
      {          BindCompaniesList(CompaniesList, valueToFilter);      }
}
```

Also in the binding code I would suggest trying

```
public static void BindList(this ListControl list, IEnumerable dataSource, string valueKey, string textKey)        
{
        list.DataSource = dataSource;
        list.DataValueField = valueKey;
        list.DataTextField = textKey;
        list.DataBind();
        list.Insert(0, new ListItem("(Empty)", "-1"));    
    }
```

Comment: I cannot place the binding into !IsPostBack, because i must databind list in PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are binding the list on PostBack, where the Datasource is having no value so make sure that the datasource is having some value while you call the method.

Comment: The datasource is full of CORRECT items, as i sayd. I think, the problem was about ViewState of ListControl. After @Andrew suggestions, I've moved binding into the Load-event - and it fills the listcontrol properly now, but didn't save the selected value. So i made solution, updated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `PreRender` event of page. 
[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

> Raised after the Page object has
>   created all controls that are required
>   in order to render the page, including
>   child controls of composite controls.